# Finding Highest Value Combination From Excel Pivot Table Filter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vba

I'm not sure if I am using the correct technique for this so please forgive me if I am way off.

I have a large range of data from previous email campaigns. I have categorised the campaigns with boolean values (Y/N) for the subject line contents e.g: *Subject Line Is Personalised*, *Subject Line Contains Urgency* etc... 
I am running the columns as Open Rate and the values as the 'Average Open Rate'. The row labels are the campaign names, and the Report Filters are all of the boolean values.

[image]

I am trying to get the 'ultimate combination' which will result in the highest average open rate. Is there a way to automate this process rather than going through and manually selected Y/N options for the filters until I find the highest average?

As an example; I'm trying to end up with is something like this:

Subjectline - Personalised Y
Subjectline - Urgency   Y
Subjectline - Product Groups    N
Subjectline - Discount Value    Y
Subjectline - Event Reference   N
Subjectline - Contains Brands   N
Subjectline - LOLS  Y

I understand that for this table it isn't that time consuming to do it manually, but I want to run a similar operation on lager data sets and frequently so it would be awesome if I could automate it.

Comment: Hi James. Was the answer below, provided three days after this old question was asked, of any use? If so, please consider replying to it, accepting it or voting on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand VBA you can try the following:

```
Sub macro1()
    Dim filters As PivotFields
    Dim combinations As Integer
    Dim reportRow As Integer
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    ' PivotTable to manipulate... pls modify yourself
    Set pt = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set filters = pt.PageFields     ' Array of all page filters
    combinations = 2 ^ filters.Count
    reportRow = 2

    ' For each combinations
    For i = 1 To combinations
        ' Set filter to {N N N} {N N Y} {N Y N} {N Y Y} {Y N N} ... etc
        For n = 0 To filters.Count - 1
            If ((i And (2 ^ n)) > 0) Then
                filters(n + 1).CurrentPage = "Y"
            Else
                filters(n + 1).CurrentPage = "N"
            End If
        Next n

        ' Extract results ... modify it yourself
        Cells(reportRow, 10).FormulaR1C1 = pt.GetData("Value")
        For n = 1 To filters.Count
            Cells(reportRow, 10 + n).FormulaR1C1 = filters(n).CurrentPage
        Next n
        reportRow = reportRow + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

The code should be self explanatory, please let me know if you need further explanation on any of the code  :)